# Reuse entire form, not just part of it

Tags: angular, html

I want to be able to reuse entire form more than once (reactive forms). I was searching for answers on the web, but only found ways to reuse part of the form and then include it in parent form (like `Address` for example).

Here is what i would like to do:
I have a model, let's say `User`. So I create a `UserComponent` with child components:

- `UserListComponent` (page with a table of all users)
- `UserCreateComponent` (page with a form to create new user + logic behind it)
- `UserDetailsComponent` (page with details about chosen user)
- `UserUpdateComponent` (page with a form to update existing user + logic behind it)

So I was wondering, is there a way to create for example `UserFormComponent` and somehow use it in both `UserCreateComponent` and `UserUpdateComponent`, so that I don't need to write that template + logic twice? Also, is there a way to handle create/update logic in parent component and not form component. For example `service.create()` would be called in `UserCreateComponent` and `service.update()` would be called in `UserUpdateComponent`.

Also, please let me know if I'm going about this completely wrong or if there is a better way to do this. I'm new to angular 2+, so I'm still figuring it out.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a suggestions. Use a common component for creating and updating without using two separate components as `UserCreateComponent` and `UserUpdateComponent`.

Let's say the common component is `UserUpsertComponent`. To identify whether the component is used to render the user create propperties or the user edit proppertis use a simple boolean `isEdit`. You can use this as an *input*.

```
<app-user-upsert-component 
    [isEdit]="true when your editing the user"
    [userData]="null when creating a user">
</app-user-upsert-component>
```

In most cases you will be naviagting to the `UserUpsertComponent` from `uUserListComponent`. So you can identify whether your coming to create a user or to edit one using the route params. Based on the route params you can make `isEdit` true or false.

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

import { UserService } from 'path/to/your/service';

import { UserData } from '../models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-upsert-component',
  styleUrls: ['./app-user-upsert-component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './app-user-upsert-component.html'
})
export class UserUpsertComponent {

  @Input()
  public isEdit: boolean;
  @Input()
  public userData: UserData;

  private form:FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private userService: UserService) { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initFormGroup();
  }

  public onFormSubmit(): void {
    const value = this.form.value;
    if (!this.isEdit) {
      this.userService.createUser(value);
    } else {
      this.userService.updateUser(value);
    }
  }

  private initFormGroup(): void {
    if (!this.isEdit) {
      this.form = this.fb.group({
        name: [null, Validators.required],
        age: [null, Validators.required]
      });
    } else {
      this.form = this.fb.group({
        name: [this.userData.name, Validators.required], //userData is a component input
        age: [this.userData.age, Validators.required]
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can create a module with a component and you will be able to export and use this form anywhere. If do you want to use a dynamic form you could do following this tutorial https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form